# Would Clickhouse merge cause increase in selected marks?

Tags: clickhouse

If clickhouse is performing a background merge operation (lets say 10 parts into 1 part), would that cause the selected marks to go up? Or are selected marks only governed by read operations performed due to `SELECT` queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not in general but it may because of partition pruning.

```sql
create table test( D date, K Int64, S String ) 
Engine=MergeTree partition by toYYYYMM(D) order by K; 

system stop merges test;

insert into test select '2022-01-01', number, '' from numbers(1000000);

insert into test select '2022-01-31', number, '' from numbers(1000000);

select name,  min_date, max_date, rows from system.parts where table = 'test' and active;
┌─name─────────┬───min_date─┬───max_date─┬────rows─┐
│ 202201_1_1_0 │ 2022-01-01 │ 2022-01-01 │ 1000000 │ two parts in a partition and min_date
│ 202201_2_2_0 │ 2022-01-31 │ 2022-01-31 │ 1000000 │ min_date & max_date are not intersecting
└──────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────┘

explain estimate select count() from test where D between '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-15';
┌─database─┬─table─┬─parts─┬────rows─┬─marks─┐
│ dw       │ test  │     1 │ 1000000 │   123 │    -- 123 mark.
└──────────┴───────┴───────┴─────────┴───────┘

system start merges test;
optimize table test final;

select name,  min_date, max_date, rows from system.parts where table = 'test' and active;
┌─name─────────┬───min_date─┬───max_date─┬────rows─┐
│ 202201_1_2_1 │ 2022-01-01 │ 2022-01-31 │ 2000000 │ one part covers the whole month
└──────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────┘

explain estimate select count() from test where D between '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-15';
┌─database─┬─table─┬─parts─┬────rows─┬─marks─┐
│ dw       │ test  │     1 │ 2000000 │   245 │     -- 245 mark.
└──────────┴───────┴───────┴─────────┴───────┘
```

In real life you will never notice this because it's very synthetic case, no filters on primary key index, and partition column is not in primary key index.

And it does not mean that merges make query slower, it means that Clickhouse is able to leverage the fact that data is not merged yet and reads only a part of the data in a partition.